# Jest/SuperTest Express integration tests - Can't set headers after they are sent. (when you call the same endpoint in multiple tests)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jestjs, supertest

This one's killing me..

I'm writing integration tests for an Express (Typescript) app, using Jest and Supertest.

I have multiple tests for the same endpoint, to test responses from when a mocked service returns data correctly and when it rejects a promise with an Error object.

The tests run fine when each request() in each it() block hits a unique end point, but when endpoints are shared between blocks I get the following error:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

This is my test code:

```
let request = null;
let app = null;
const async = require('async');

import GError from '../../src/services/ErrorService';

const { list } = require('../../src/controllers/RecipeController');

let throwError: boolean = false;
let error = null;
const errorMsg: string = 'Something went wrong!';

const listData: Array<object> = [{id: 1, base: 'something'}];

jest.mock('../../src/services/RecipeService', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        list: jest.fn(() => {
            if (throwError) {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
            return Promise.resolve(listData);
        })
    }));
});

beforeEach(() => {
    request = require('supertest');
    app = require('../../src/app');
});

afterEach( ( done ) => {
    throwError = false;
    error = null;
    app.close( () => {
       delete require.cache[require.resolve('../../src/app')];
       done();
    });
});

describe('Root Path', () => {

    it('should return a welcome message', (done) => {

        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.text).toEqual('Test API.');
                expect(res.statusCode).toBe(200);
                done();
            });

    });

});

describe('Recipe List', () => {

    it('should call controller and return correct response when successful or error is thrown in service', (done) => {

        const path: string = '/recipes/list';

        request(app)
            .get(path)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(JSON.parse(res.text)).toEqual({
                    recipes: listData
                });
                done();
            });

    });

    it('should return an error response if service rejects promise', (done) => {

        throwError = true;
        error = new GError(errorMsg);

        const path: string = '/recipes/list';

        request(app)
            .get(path)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(JSON.parse(res.text)).toEqual({
                    errors: {
                        message: errorMsg
                    }
                });
                done();
            });

    });


});
```

I think I need to reset the app in between tests, which is what I'm trying to achieve with:

```
beforeEach(() => {
   request = require('supertest');
   app = require('../../src/app');
});
```

But with no joy. Can anyone shine a light?

UPDATE:

Here's the controller method the route hits:

```
exports.list = async (req, res, next) => {

    const recipes: IRecipeList = await recipeService.list().catch(err => {
        return next(err);
    });

    const response: IRecipeListResponse = {recipes};

    res.status(200).json(response);

};
```

**SOLVED**:

So it turned out to be nothing to do with Jest / Superagent (I was sure it was to do with one of these). Strangely though I only get this error in the context of running integration tests, there is no error when hitting the end point in Postman - which was super confusing.

**PROBLEM**:

```
    exports.list = async (req, res, next) => {

        const recipes: IRecipeList = await recipeService.list().catch(err => { .          //this doesn't stop the execution past this await
            return next(err);
        });

        //this still gets processed if the service rejects the promise 
        const response: IRecipeListResponse = {recipes};

        res.status(200).json(response);

    };
```

**SOLUTION**:

```
exports.list = async (req, res, next) => {

    let error = false;

    const recipes: IRecipeList = await recipeService.list().catch(err => {
        error = true;
        return next(err);
    });

    if (error) {
        return;
    }

    const response: IRecipeListResponse = {recipes};

    return res.status(200).json(response);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you send response more than once.

Comment: It only occurs in the context of running unit tests with jest (and superagent). If i hit this end point in Postman it's fine (if I mash the send button it's still fine).